# Как мне по упоминанию участника получить его ник в дискорд канале?

Tags: python, phpmyadmin, discord, discord.py, discord-api

пишу дискорд бота который по упоминанию какого либо участника сервера (при чем упоминается не Имя пользователя, а его ник на этом канале) выдавал бы какую либо информацию по этому участнику из базы данных PHPMyAdmin. Но я не совсем понимаю как сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()

async def user(ctx, user : discord.User):
    
   # do your expensive stuff here
```

При вызове команды, человек должен указать значение "user" - упоминание, айди, имя, имя#дискриминатор.
Далее вы уже делаете то, что вам необходимо.